# how to do image registration of affinically/projective different images

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, affinetransform

I have 2 images.

Image 1 - just an image.
Image 2 - an (approximately) affine transformation of image 1.

What is the best way to do affine image registration for those 2 images, meaning finding the affine transformation matrix between them?

What is the best way to do projective image registration for those 2 images, meaning finding the projective transformation matrix between them?

If it matters, the images are both aerial photographs, taken at intervals of 50 to 2000 milliseconds.

If you recommend some off the shelf code, my priorities are:

1. Matlab
2. Python (opencv?)
3. Others

Comment: I suspect you are more likely to get an answer if you provide sample images...

Comment: keypoint matching is a good start (general purpose image image registration). Try Sift and similar. Finding the affine homography from keypoint correspondences is typically done with a RANSAC approach. Depending on the image material other approaches might be faster and/or better, but keypoint matching typically is ok for most kind of image data.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the matrix with the help of `OPENCV`(python)

```
M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
```

`M` is the transformation matrix between them.